# Comparing values of fetched data with input data of different contracts

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

Given two contracts as follows, contract `TestData` calls contract `Reg` to fetch data that had already been stored in its map using `get_attributes` function.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;
contract Reg {
    mapping (address=>bytes32[5]) Map;

    //Filling the map
    function fill_map(bytes32[5] _attributes) public  {
            Map[msg.sender] = _attributes;
    }

    //Returns data in the map corresponding to an address
    function get_attributes(address _id) view public returns (bytes32[5]){
        return Map[_id];
    }
}


contract TestData {

    address Address;
    function get_address (address _Address) public{   
        Address = _Address;
    } 

    //Retreive data from Reg contract
    bytes32[5] fetched;
    function fetch(address _reg_Adress) public view returns (bytes32[5]) {
        Reg r = Reg(_reg_Adress);
        fetched = r.get_attributes(Address);
        return (fetched);
    }

    //Retreive input data from user
    bytes32[5] inputs;
    function getInputs(bytes32[5] _inputs) public view returns (bytes32[5]){
            inputs = _inputs;
            return (inputs);
    }    

    //Compare input data with fetched data
    bool[5] a = [false,false,false,false,false];
    function compare() public view returns(bool[5]){
        for(uint i=0;i<5;i++){
            for(uint j=0;j<5;j++){
                if(inputs[i] == fetched[j]){
                    a[i] = true;                 
                }
            }
        }

        return (a);
    }  

}
```

This is how I test it:

1. Fill the map with `["0x0","0x1","0x2","0x3","0x4"]`
2. For user input I also input `["0x0","0x1","0x2","0x3","0x4"]`

The output is correct returning `[true,true,true,true,true]`.

However, if I change the input say, `["0xA","0x1","0x2","0x3","0x4"]`, the output remains `[true,true,true,true,true]` although it should be `[false,true,true,true,true]`.

Does something happen to the data as it is being fetched from the Reg contract? When I try testing the same code but with two input arrays rather than fetching the data, it works fine.

Also, I have been looking for other ways to do the comparisons. Is there any other efficient way other than looping?

Comment: Don't you want `i<5` and `j<5`? You're stopping after comparing 3 elements.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I fixed it in the question. However, it is still not working when I change the input values.

Comment: Then can you update the question with the current results? What are the values for which it works and what are the values for which it doesn't work? What is the output in both cases?

Comment: Are you perhaps calling `compare` as a transaction? If so, it will permanently modify `a`, and subsequent calls will inherit the values in there. (Once an element is set to `true`, it will never go back.) You should probably just move the declaration of `a` inside `compare()` anyway.

Comment: Ah, @Jaime's answer points out another issue. Your nested loop means you're testing whether each element in `input` matches _any_ element of `fetched`. If you only want to match corresponding elements, you need to drop the inner loop as suggested in that answer.

Comment: I tried inserting a inside compare() but that did not work either. It continues to remain [true,true,true,true,true]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `compare` is almost right, the errors are elsewhere

```
function fetch(address _reg_Adress) public view returns (bytes32[5])
```

you have to remove `view` from here

```
function getInputs(bytes32[5] _inputs) public view returns (bytes32[5])
```

also from here.

Then move your array into the function and define it as memory.

```
//Compare input data with fetched data
function compare() public view returns(bool[5]){
    bool[5] memory a = [false,false,false,false,false];

    for(uint i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(uint j=0;j<5;j++){
            if(inputs[i] == fetched[j]){
                a[i] = true;                 
            }
        }
    }

    return (a);
}
```

if not, you should remove `view` also from the method `compare` to make it work

after this changes the result would be `false,true,true,true,true` as expected.

Comment: How did removing view solve the problem?

Comment: if you define the function as view you can't change the contract state (eg its variables) so the value of the members of the contract are not the one expected.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

First your `for` loop is stopping early, at 3 when the limit should be i<5.

Also your second `for` is not necessary. Your function can be:

```
function compare() public view returns(bool[5]){
    bool[5] memory a;
    for(uint i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(uint j=0;j<5;j++){
            if(inputs[i] == fetched[j]){
                a[i] = true;                 
            }
        }
    }

    return (a);
}
```

You could also do the follwoing to ensure `a` is updated etither when the values is true or false:

```
function compare() public view returns(bool[5]){
    bool[5] memory a;
    for(uint i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(uint j=0;j<5;j++){
            a[i] = (inputs[i] == fetched[j]);                 
        }
    }

    return (a);
}
```

finally, your functions modify state variables so these cannot be view.

Hope this helps

**UPDATE: Full code.**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;
contract Reg {
    mapping (address=>bytes32[5]) public Map;

    //Filling the map
    function fill_map(bytes32[5] _attributes) public  {
            Map[msg.sender] = _attributes;
    }

    //Returns data in the map corresponding to an address
    function get_attributes(address _id) view public returns (bytes32[5]){
        return Map[_id];
    }
}


contract TestData {

    address Address;
    function get_address (address _Address) public{   
        Address = _Address;
    } 

    //Retreive data from Reg contract
    bytes32[5] public fetched;
    function fetch(address _reg_Adress) public returns (bytes32[5]) {
        Reg r = Reg(_reg_Adress);
        fetched = r.get_attributes(Address);
        return (fetched);
    }

    //Retreive input data from user
    bytes32[5] public inputs;
    function getInputs(bytes32[5] _inputs) public returns (bytes32[5]){
            inputs = _inputs;
            return (inputs);
    }    

    //Compare input data with fetched data

    function compare() public view returns(bool[5]){
        bool[5] memory a;
        for(uint i=0;i<5;i++){
            for(uint j=0;j<5;j++){
                if(inputs[i] == fetched[j]){
                    a[i] = true;                 
                }
            }
        }

        return (a);
    }  

}
```

Comment: You are right about stopping early. I did fix that. However, your if statement compares each element in the first array with the corresponding element in the other array. I am trying to find whether each element in the first array is in the second array or not. Therefore, I believe I need the second loop.

Comment: Then yes, the second loop is necessary. I edited the answer. Let me know if this solves your problem

Comment: It does not. Array a continues to return [true,true,true,true,true]

Comment: I just modified the code, this works for me in remix. The issue is that when you try the first time `a` is all true. Then you tried with something that gives `false`, but your code only update `a` when is true so the true value is not changed. Putting it inside, initialize a to false when the function is executed. Let me know

Comment: Try it out with a false test case at first. For example, ["0x0","0x1","0x2","0x3","0x4"] and ["0xA","0x1","0x2","0x3","0x4"] should give [false,true,true,true,true], however it still gives [true,true,true,true,true].

Comment: no, it works fine for me.

Comment: I updated the answer and added the full code, just in case. I tried it several times and it works